# Can't append table to div

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dom

I created a table using d3.js library,
but when I try to append the table to a div, it gives an error?

code:

```
<head>
<script src="../../d3.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="main">
Hi
</div>

<script>
  const table = d3.create("table");
  const tbody = table.append("tbody");

  var i,j,row;
  for(i=0;i<5;i++){
    row =tbody.append("tr");
    for(j=0;j<3;j++){
      row.append("td").text(`${i},${j}`);
    }
  } 
  console.log(typeof(table));
  console.log(table);

  node =table.node();
  console.log(typeof(node));
  console.log(node);

  d3.select("#main").append(node);


</script>

</body>

</html>
```

but I get an error:
[image: error when I try to append table to div]

although my code similar to what is in this tutorial
[A tutorial on d3js](https://observablehq.com/@d3/lets-make-a-bar-chart?collection=@d3/lets-make-a-bar-chart)

Comment: Did you try `d3.select("#main").append(table);`? I think that `node()` is specific to observablehq.

Comment: @Mehdi I surely tried d3.select("#main").append(table); first, but also gave me error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Observable tutorials are meant to create Observable notebooks. There are several small differences between Observable and a regular D3 running in a browser.

That being said, the only problem in your approach is that `append` requires either a string with the tag name or the element. If you have a string, just use it as `append("foo")`. However, if you have the element to be appended (in your case, `table.node()`), you have to return it from a function.

So, instead of:

```
d3.select("#main").append(node);
```

It has to be:

```
d3.select("#main").append(() => node);
```

Here is your code with that change only:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">
  Hi
</div>

<script>
  const table = d3.create("table");
  const tbody = table.append("tbody");

  var i, j, row;
  for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    row = tbody.append("tr");
    for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
      row.append("td").text(`${i},${j}`);
    }
  }
  node = table.node();

  d3.select("#main").append(() => node);
</script>
```

Finally, if you are writing regular scripts for a browser, just ditch this `d3.create()` followed by `append(() => selection.node())`. Use a simple tag string instead.